# C# context error

Tags: c#

I get an error for the last line that it does not exist in the current context. Why is that?    why can't you use write line outside of the methods if the methods are static not private?
Thanks

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace SimpleMethod5
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                car();

            }

            static void car()
            {
                string myCar = "Nissan";
                Console.WriteLine(myCar);
            }

            Console.Writeline();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A program needs a starting point to execute, and in C# Console programs it is the Main() method. Then after that the execution follows the path directed by the Main(), that is if it calls a function it goes on and executes the function and control is returned to Main() again etc. (Of course this explanation is considering single-threaded programs.)

So you cannot write a method call (which is what Console.WriteLine() is) inside a class as the program wouldn't know when to call it.